# ggplot2 pass variable to plot to a function

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I use ggplot to use multiple plots, so I built my own function.

```
plothist <- function(a) {
  ggplot(aes(x = a), data = data) + geom_histogram()
}

p1 <- plothist(data$fixed.acidity)
p2 <- plothist(data$volatile.acidity)
p3 <- plothist(data$citric.acid)
p4 <- plothist(data$residual.sugar)
p5 <- plothist(data$chlorides)
p6 <- plothist(data$free.sulfur.dioxide)
p7 <- plothist(data$total.sulfur.dioxide)
p8 <- plothist(data$density)
p9 <- plothist(data$pH)
p10 <- plothist(data$sulphates)
p11 <- plothist(data$alcohol)

x <- grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11,
                  top = "Histogram of independent variables")
x
```

the x-axis does not have the name of the variable, I only can see "a" on every plot, which makes the plots pretty useless. Can you help me how to display the actual variable there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `aes_string` for this kind of programming:

```
library(ggplot2)

plothist <- function(data, column) {
  ggplot(data, aes_string(x = column)) + geom_histogram()
}

plothist(data, "fixed.acidity")
```

Comment: What if you want to mix string with non-string? One can use `aes(get("STRING"), non-STRING)`, but what about `aes_string("STRING", non-STRING)`?

Comment: @PoGibas, I would strongly suggest avoiding non-standard evaluation in functions.  If you really need to do this, use `aes_`.  I'm not good at using it, because I've never found it necessary.  Usually, adding columns inside the function and referring to them by name results in simpler code.

Answer (score 2):

Your function needs only minor edits:

```
plotHist <- function(inputData, columnToPlot) {
    # Load library as your function doesn't know
    # what is this ggplot function you want to use
    library(ggplot2)
    resultPlot <- ggplot(inputData, aes(get(columnToPlot))) + 
        geom_histogram() +
        labs(x = columnToPlot)
    return(resultPlot)
}
plotHist(mtcars, "cyl")
```

`columnToPlot` is name of a column you want to plot. Also you need to pass `inputData` argument as your given function doesn't know what `dinputData` is.